# Forms that comprise of two models

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to create a model form in Django. This form has inputs for first_name, last_name, email, and contact_request.

I have two models:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # phone_number =
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "home_users"


class ContactRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField("Date/time created")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "home_contactrequests"
```

In my form, upon submission, because there is a OneToMany relationship between `Users` and `ContactRequests`, a new row will be added to both `home_users` and `home_contactrequests` when there is a new email submitted through the form. If the email exists in the `home_users` table, then a new row will only be added to `home_contactrequests` with it's foreign key referencing a `user.id`

I'm not quite sure how to implement this right now as I am new to model forms and Django as well. I was wondering if someone could guide me to show me the process and logic involved in creating this type of form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) on the `User` model to fetch a user if one with that email already exists:

Here is one way you would wire this up in your view:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                                                  first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                                                  last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
        ContactRequest.objects.create(user=obj,
                                      message=form.cleaned_data['message'],
                                      datetime_created=datetime.datetime.now())
        return redirect('/thanks')
     return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

You can help yourself a bit by setting the [`auto_now_add` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the `datetime_created` field; this way your timestamp is automatically saved.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it. I understand the logic you presented to me. However for my situation I am trying to perform an AJAX submission of my form. If you dont mind looking, here is a snippet of what I have http://dpaste.com/33F5WRD I am just confused as to how to put these pieces together. If you want to see the project as a whole: https://github.com/liondancer/django-boothie